# Saving files in localfolder in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

i have used following code to select multiple files in my Windows 8 app.

```csharp
FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
fileOpenPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select Files";
fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
var files = await fileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
```

now i want to save the selected files within my application folder but could now find a way to do so. So can anyone help me out on this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want copy all the files in local folder.

```csharp
FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
fileOpenPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select Files";
fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
var files = await fileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

foreach (var f in files)
{
    await f.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, f.Name, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for accessing application data go through

[accessing app data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx)

But if you want to store data in the installed location(if u mena that  by application folder)

then it is not possible as installed directory is read only . youcannot add files or write to any files withing but yes you can read . :-)